# how to remove quotation marks inside unclosed quotations marks

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to remove quotation marks in notepad++ inside unclosed quotations marks with regex? Example: `"Film name was "Pulp Fiction""` -> `"Film name was Pulp Fiction"`

Comment: How is this a Java question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex `(?<!^)"(?!$)`.

This regex will not match double quotes at the beginning and end of the string.

Check out [here](https://regex101.com/r/fF7iY5/1) and read more explanation about regex in the link provided on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all quotation marks.
2. Add quotation marks at beginning and end.